# How do I show alert message when field/s is not empty and button is not click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html form with 4 fields which is 1) Department 2) Phone 3) Employees 4) Date. So If user press the **save_department_number** button without enter anything on the fields I can show a error message using jquery/ajax.

But now I want to show a alert message **WHEN** all field/fields is not empty BUT user forgot to click **save_department_button** button. How can I do this using JQuery / Javascript ?

**Here is my html form**

```
<div id="column3">
<form id="save_department">

    <table border="0" width="520">          
    <div id="success"></div>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" valign="top"><b>Add Department Number <hr></b></td>
        <td colspan="1" align="right"><a id="addmore">Add more (+)</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>                 
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" align="right" width="170"><input type="submit" class="search_submit" value="Save Department Number"><input type="hidden" name="cid" value="<?php echo $cid; ?>"></td>                  
    </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="department_box">
    <table border="0" width="510">          
        <tr>                
            <td valign="top" width="135"><b>Department</b></td>
            <td valign="top" width="135"><b>Phone</b></td>
            <td valign="top" width="75"><b>Employees</b></td>
            <td valign="top"><b>Date</b></td>
        </tr>   
        <?php
        $depart_row_check  = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM company_department WHERE cid = '$cid' ");
        $num_depart_row_check =  mysqli_num_rows($depart_row_check);

        if($num_depart_row_check == 0){             
            ?>
            <tr id="clone">             
                <td><input type="text" name="department[]" class="medium" id="department" value="" placeholder="department"><input type="hidden" name="new[]" value="new" /></td>           
                <td><input type="text" name="phone[]" class="medium" id="phone" value="" placeholder="phone"></td>          
                <td><input type="text" name="employee[]" class="small" id="employee" value="" placeholder="employees"></td>         
                <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="" class="date" placeholder="date"></td>
            </tr>

            <?php   

        }else{

                $depart_row_check  = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM company_department WHERE cid = '$cid' ");
                while($fetch_department =  mysqli_fetch_array($depart_row_check)){
                    $department_d = stripslashes($fetch_department['department']);
                    $phone_d = stripslashes($fetch_department['phone']);
                    $employee_d = stripslashes($fetch_department['employee']);
                    $updated_d = stripslashes($fetch_department['updated']);
                    $com_d_id = (int) $fetch_department['com_d_id'];

                    ?>  
                    <tr id="clone">             
                    <td><input type="text" name="department[]" class="medium" id="department" value="<?php echo $department_d; ?>" placeholder="department">
                        <input type="hidden" name="existing[]" value="<?php echo $com_d_id; ?>" /></td>         
                    <td><input type="text" name="phone[]" class="medium" id="phone" value="<?php echo $phone_d; ?>" placeholder="phone"></td>           
                    <td><input type="text" name="employee[]" class="small" id="employee" value="<?php echo $employee_d; ?>" placeholder="employees"></td>           
                    <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="date" value="<?php echo $updated_d; ?>" placeholder="date"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php

                }                   

        }           

        ?>
        <div class="apendto"></div>

    </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

May be It can be done using this but can't complete it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).click(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is('#save_department,#save_department *')) {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Hi");            
    }
});
});
```

Comment: you should be clearer about when that alert will pop up. For example, when the user leaves page? Or after a while?

Comment: only showing alert message when user click anything outside the form.

Comment: That's mean save_department id.

Comment: So if a user input something in the form, then focus something outside the form, then the alert pop up?

Comment: No. If user input something in the form field/s but forgot to press the save button (#save_department_number) then a alert message will be show.  Forgot to press the save button means user can click any other link outside of the FORM.

Comment: try using a timed function that checks if a value is present in the fields & if present then alert message

Comment: That's what I'm asking. How do you define one from not remembering to press save? After a exact time without save? Or go to another page without hitting save button?